# how to change my own js library selector to be as jquery selector $()

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple javascript library and I want to inquire about something In order to do I do .

Firsly: this is
**a Part of code from my JS library**

```
(function() {
    var lib = {
        elems: [],
        getElem: function() {
            var tmpElem = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
                tmpElem.push(document.getElementById(arguments[i]));
            this.elems = tmpElem;
            tmpElem = null;
            return this;
        },
        html: function(txt) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].innerHTML = txt;
            return this;
        },
        style: function(prob, val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].style[prob] = val;
            return this;
        },
        addEvent: function(event, callback) {
            if (this.elems[0].addEventListener) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                    this.elems[i].addEventListener(event, callback, false);
            } else if (this.elems[0].attachEvent) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                    this.elems[i].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
            }
            return this;
        },
        toggle: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].style.display = (this.elems[i].style.display === 'none' || '') ? 'block' : 'none';
            return this;
        },
        domLoad: function(callback) {
            var isLoaded = false;
            var checkLoaded = setInterval(function() {
                if (document.body && document.getElementById)
                    isLoaded = true;
            }, 10);
            var Loaded = setInterval(function() {
                if (isLoaded) {
                    clearInterval(checkLoaded);
                    clearInterval(Loaded);
                    callback();
                }
            }, 10);
        }
    };

    var fn = lib.getElem;
    for(var i in lib)
        fn[i] = lib[i];

    window.lib = window.$ = fn;
})();
```

Now we will continue .....

As we know in jquery, when pointing to a specified element we using like this

```
$('#id').show // or
$(document).ready  // and so on
```

and My library used by this way.

```
$.getElem('id')
```

Now how can I change the this part `$.getElem('id')` In order to be `$()` as in jquery.

> ////////////////////// **New modification** /////////////////////////////

After applied `@Peter Olson` answer, show to me an error message `TypeError: $(...).html is not a function`.

What's the reason of this error message ?

Comment: While running along side jQuery?

Comment: To achieve that, `lib` should be a function.

Comment: @asawyer: Maybe yes maybe no

Comment: Can you please tell me simple example.

Comment: Why not look at jQuery's source?

Comment: @Lee Taylor: Because Jquery source very big and complex too

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `$` a function, and then add properties to it.

```
(function() {
    var lib = {
        // ...
    };
    var fn = lib.getElem;
    for(var i in lib) {
      fn[i] = lib[i];
    }
    window.lib = window.$ = fn;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have small inquire `var fn = lib.getElem; for(var i in lib) { fn[i] = lib[i]; }`, the previous part I don't understand it well. can you explain it please.

Comment: It assigns the `lib.getElem` function to `fn`, and then adds all the properties of `lib` to `fn`. Then, when you call `fn`, it's just as if you called `lib.getElem`, but you can get all the properties that were in `lib` with `fn`.

Comment: To use, you do `$("id")`, or `$.getElem("id")`.

Comment: Thanks, when using `$.getElem('id')` works without any error, but `$('id')` not work and shows me error when using any method , `TypeError: $(...).style is not a function`. style is method belong to the object lib.

Comment: I can't tell you where the error is coming from, I think it's probably in part of the code that you didn't include in the question.

Comment: Ok, See my question again, I have updated and included  all the code of my library. you can now see what the reason of that problem.